Prevent Canvas from following
Here's my hierarchy:
Main Camera
Follow Camera (Cinemachine Virtual Camera, body is Framing Transposer)
Canvas (one TextMeshPro item)
Player
The follow camera correctly follows the player as he moves around. But the canvas also moves. I want the canvas to remain static in the world. Is this possible?
If it's not possible, how can I have text overlays in a scene without using a canvas? I have scenes that will load and unload as the player moves around (RPG type open world game), but each scene has a visible number on it that should be "burned in" to the scene and not move with the camera.

well you can make the canvas world based, not camera based,

On the Canvas object, in the Inspector go to Canvas -> Render Mode, set to World Space. Then resize the canvas to the screen area and adjust the font as needed.
